# Newtonsoft JSON десереализация, поля объектов по умолчанию не меняются

Tags: c#, json

Итак, есть тестовый класс и билбиотека Newtonsoft.JSON

```
public class TestClass1
{
    public List<string> List1;
    private string _string1;

    public string String1
    {
        get { return _string1; }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Меняем строку 1: {_string1}");
            _string1 = value;
            Console.WriteLine($"Строка 1 изменена: {_string1}");
        }
    }

    public TestClass1()
    {
        List1 = new List<string>() {"Default Item0", "Default Item1", "Default Item2" };
        _string1 = "<строка по умолчанию>";
    }
}
```

использование:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass1 tc1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass1>("{\"List1\":[\"Deserialized Item0\",\"Deserialized Item1\",\"Deserialized Item2\"], \"String1\":\"Deserialized string\"}");
        Console.WriteLine($"tc1.List1[0] = {tc1.List1[0]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"tc1.String1 = {tc1.String1}");
        Console.ReadLine();
        //Результат
        //Меняем строку 1: <строка по умолчанию>
        //Строка 1 изменена: Deserialized string
        //tc1.List1[0] = Default Item0
        //tc1.String1 = Deserialized string
    }
```

Вопрос: **почему некоторые поля по умолчанию НЕ перезаписываются?**
Ведь десереализация по идее должна проходить по алгоритму: создать объект конструктором без параметров, прочитать существующие поля в строке и изменить соответствующие поля у обьекта. Разве не так?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте свойство вместо поля.

```
public List<string> List1 { get; set; }
```

*Update*

Да, @Новичок, Вы правы, поторопился.

Добавьте такую строчку после десериализации:

```
Console.WriteLine("Count = " + tc1.List1.Count);
```

Понимаете, в чем дело? Их стало шесть, так как новые строки добавились в существовавший список. Этого можно избежать, используя дополнительный параметр `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() 
{ 
  ObjectCreationHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ObjectCreationHandling.Replace 
};
string content = "{\"List1\":[\"Deserialized Item0\",\"Deserialized Item1\",\"Deserialized Item2\"], \"String1\":\"Deserialized string\"}";
TestClass1 tc1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass1>(content, settings);
```

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ObjectCreationHandling.htm
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObjectCreationHandling.htm

Значение по умолчанию, очевидно, `Auto` (0).

Comment: Ваш код проблему не решает, да и объяснения нету.

Comment: Да, подозревал что можно было решить через настройки десериализации. Но я всё-же полагаю что последовательность действий должна быть такой которую описал в вопросе, с **заменой** полей по умолчанию. В рамках вопроса было бы не плохо разобраться в этой особенности :)

Comment: @Новичок Судя по тому, что мы видим, разработчики Newtonsoft полагают по-другому.